Total percent change in a column in R?
I have a panel dataset in R that documents the percent change in population for cities over several years. A simplified version looks like this:
city_pop<-tibble(city=c("NYC", "NYC", "LA", "LA"), 
       percentpopchange=c("0.1", "0.2", "0.5", "0.3"), 
       year=c(1980, 1981, 1980, 1981))

I would like to compute the total population change (in percentage) for NYC and LA over 1980 and 1981. For example, that would be 0.32 for NYC. My ideal dataset with such output would be:
cum_city_pop<-tibble(city=c("NYC", "LA"), 
       total_percentpopchange=c("0.32", "0.95"))

Is there any way to do this in R? I would greatly appreciate any help.

The percentages in your desired output don‘t match to the percentages in your input, i.e. I don‘t see how you‘d get from 0.1 and 0.2 to a 0.32 change.

Assuming your 0.93 for LA is a typo:
library(dplyr)

city_pop <- tibble(
  city = c("NYC", "NYC", "LA", "LA"), 
  percentpopchange = c("0.1", "0.2", "0.5", "0.3"), 
  year = c(1980, 1981, 1980, 1981)
)

city_pop %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  summarize(
    total_percentpopchange = as.character(
      prod(1 + as.numeric(percentpopchange)) - 1
  ))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   city  total_percentpopchange
#>   <chr> <chr>                 
#> 1 LA    0.95                  
#> 2 NYC   0.32

Created on 2024-09-03 with reprex v2.1.1

If we assume the population of NY is 1,000 in 1980, then its population changes as follows after 1980 and 1981:
1980: $1000 + $1000*0.1 = $1100
1981: $1100 + $1100*0.2 = $1320.
So throughout 1980 and 1981, the population of NY increased by a factor of:
($1320-$1000)/$1000 = 0.32.
Some R code that computes this is pasted below:
city_pop<-tibble(city=c("NYC", "NYC", "LA", "LA"), 
                 percentpopchange=c("0.1", "0.2", "0.5", "0.3"), 
                 year=c(1980, 1981, 1980, 1981))
city_pop$percentpopchange <- as.numeric(city_pop$percentpopchange)

cum_city_pop_final <- tibble(city=unique(city_pop$city))

unique_cities <- unique(city_pop$city)
total_percent_pop_changes <- c()
for (i in 1:length(unique(city_pop$city))){
  pop <- 100
  for (j in 1:length(unique(city_pop$year))){
    pop <- pop + pop * city_pop$percentpopchange[which(city_pop$city==unique(city_pop$city)[i] & city_pop$year==unique(city_pop$year)[j])]
    if (j==length(unique(city_pop$year))){
      total_percent_pop_changes <- c(total_percent_pop_changes, (pop-100)/100)
    }
  }
}

cum_city_pop_final$total_percentpopchange <- total_percent_pop_changes

By the way, I think the total percentage population change for LA throughout 1980-1981 would be 0.95, not 0.93.
